# My rectangle program for android runs successfully, but when I run in my device I see a black screen and not red rectangle

Tags: android

My rectangle program for android runs successfully, but when I run in my device I see a black screen and not red rectangle.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a 0 width/0 height bounds for your rect when calling Canvas.drawRect.

Also, try to avoid creating objects in your onDraw method as this will cause thrash with garbage collection.

Try this instead:

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
    private Paint p;

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        p = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        p.setColor(Color.RED);

        //canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100, p);

        int left = 100;
        int top = 100;
        int right = left + 100;
        int bottom = top + 100;

        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is correct. But I used in the four primary parameters with the same values like  "Hundred".For example,  canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 100,100,p);  it displays black screen  and if we use for example, canvas.drawRect(100,100,150,150,p); it displays red rectangle.

Comment: Keep in mind that the params are left, top, right, bottom.  Not x, y, w, h.  You were specifying a left and right edge at x-coordinate 100 and a top and bottom edge at y-coordinate 100 which makes an empty rectangle.